# Is it possible to track views and clones of my github repositories

Tags: github

Just wondering if there is any Analytics type things available for github. I'd be curious to know who is viewing / using my code, if anyone...

Comment: Note: the traffic graph now includes the **number of clones**: See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12854365/6309)

Answer (score 40):

All analytics for a GitHub repository is available at

```
https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>/graphs/traffic
```

Answer (score 20):

Update August 2014:

The Traffic graph now includes the **number of clones**: See "[Clone Graphs](https://github.com/blog/1873-clone-graphs)"

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/395621/3867646/2c340b8a-2009-11e4-8823-9ddda44b51e0.png]

The [2020 documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/visualizing-repository-data-with-graphs/viewing-traffic-to-a-repository)  states:

> Anyone with push access to a repository can view its traffic, including full clones (not fetches), visitors from the past 14 days, referring sites, and popular content in the traffic graph.

---

All the information are mainly available through the [(newly refurbished) User page](https://github.com/blog/1256-new-user-profile-pages).

But you can query some of those data through the [Github API for users](http://developer.github.com/v3/users/), as described in "[How I built my blog in one day](http://erjjones.github.com/blog/How-I-built-my-blog-in-one-day/)"

> I wanted to have a button with my number of GitHub followers and GitHub repositories that was dynamic.
> GitHub provides an api of each users information:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        $('#gf').text('GitHub Followers');
        $('#gfr').text('GitHub Repos'); 

$.get('https://api.github.com/users/erjjones', function(res) {
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(res);    
if(typeof obj.followers != 'undefined') 
{   
$('#gf').text(obj.followers + ' GitHub Followers');
$('#gfr').text(obj.public_repos + ' GitHub Repos'); 
}   
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Are there any similar tools for Bitbucket as well?

Comment: @PavanKotesh https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/6802/how-can-i-see-a-graph-of-work-done-by-me and https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/4307/feature-request-contributor-statistics-bb say "no, not yet". That feature request is in progress though.

Comment: @Akhila I have updated the 2020 documentation, but beside that, the 2014 feature is still there without much evolution.

Answer (score 0):

(disclaimer: I started building this)

https://github.com/jgehrcke/github-repo-stats is a GitHub Action that periodically queries data about total/unique views, total/unique clones (and more, such as stargazers, forks, ...) from the GitHub HTTP API. It persists the data, and generates an HTML report with various charts. The report is also generated as a PDF doc (with vector graphics! : ))

A screenshot of a part of the report: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmbbo.png

A demo report is linked in the main README at https://github.com/jgehrcke/github-repo-stats.

[image]