# Getting Git Clone history

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to figure out how to get who has made clones from git or git hub.  Is there a git command that can do this?

Git hub reports clones made but not who made them.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

On Github you can see the amount of forks in your repository:

[image]

When you click on the number, you should see *which users* cloned the repo. For instance:

[image]

Keep in mind that clones can exist outside of Github too (e.g. Azure DevOps, GitLab, *et cetera*), 
and that only Github clones are displayed here :)

afaik there is no git command that can retrieve this info for any remote repository, but there's a big chance that the brand new [GitHub client](https://github.blog/2020-09-17-github-cli-1-0-is-now-available/) can.

Answer (score 0):

Github tracks clones under **Insights > Traffic**, which can be retrieved using the command line:

```
curl -u [username]:[password] https://api.github.com/repos/[owner]/[repo]/traffic/clones
```

However, Github does not have data showing *who* cloned repositories.

#### See also

- [**Can the owner of a repo see clones?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20927871/1164465)
- [**Is there a way to get download/clone statistics of a git repository?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697557/1164465)