# Get information about Clones, Unique Clones, Views and Unique Visitors using github API

Tags: github, github-api

[image]

Is there any way to get information (*in JSON or Java objects*) about Clones, Unique Clones, Views and Unique Visitors using github API on the basis of date or month or year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of: both the [repos API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/) and the [statistic API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/) do not expose those data.

All you have are "[followers](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/followers/)" ([as I mentioned in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12854365/6309)) but `https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>/graphs/traffic` remains the only source for traffic-related data.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is a bit late (almost 6 years), but, is [this](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#traffic) what you're looking for? Following the link, we see two examples to download `clones` information from a github repo:

In order to download the clones in `shell`, use:

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/traffic/clones
```

In order to download the clones in `javascript`, use:

```
await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/traffic/clones', {
  owner: 'octocat',
  repo: 'hello-world'
})
```

The result is a `JSON` object:

```
{
  "count": 173,
  "uniques": 128,
  "clones": [
    {
      "timestamp": "2016-10-10T00:00:00Z",
      "count": 2,
      "uniques": 1
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

The `...` indicate more values (follow the link for the complete example).